# Cannot found image when pickup from my app

Tags: android, camera

i have write an app like camera on android. But when pick an imagefrom my app, it have error can not found image.

```
imvpick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent pickIntent = new Intent("inline-data");
            if (pickIntent != null) {
                pickIntent.putExtra("data", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picker));
                setResult(RESULT_OK, pickIntent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

and in manifest

```
  <activity android:name=".CameraActivity" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Can you please post the error

Comment: Thansk for comment. i want take picture from hangout and choice in list from my app. but when finish my activity, hangout show the toast "cannot found image"

Comment: i guess you have written for onclick functionality when ever that button or view is clicked at that situtation it will send the image and are you using startActivityForResult(); or startActivity()?

Comment: i call PickupActivity when choice "take picture" in hangouts. Then choice a image in list, i want when click to a image, it can show in hangout.